# Writing to file with name = date

Tags: c

I would like to write to a file that is one directory under me but for some reason I keep getting errors, I think because of the end of file tag of my buffer. Like something like cd .. then cd directoryToWriteTo and the name has to be the current timestamp.
It keeps telling that opening is null and filename is the date + EOF which I think is the problem? also filename has to be static .

```
static char * filename ;


int main(){

   generateName();


FILE * opening;
opening = fopen(filename,"aw");
if(opening == null){
fprintf("couldn't write to file");
fprintf(filename);
}
}

void generateName(){
 time_t current_time;
 struct tm *localtime;
 char buffer[80];
 current_time = time(NULL);
 localtime=  localtime(&current_time);
 if (localtime== NULL ){ exit(-1);}
 strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M", localtime);
 filenaam = buffer;
 // How can i make it so it goes to a directory under him ?
 }
```

It also has to work with linux and windows.

Comment: Does the directory exist? What goes wrong when you try?

Comment: Is there ```null``` in ```C```?

Comment: directory exists, but currently I am just trying to make the name work without going to other directorys, with filename being 2018_10_28_10_44@■f

Comment: What is "under me" and "under him"?

Comment: so currently i am in /maindir/afile and have to go to /maindir/other

Comment: Notice that if for some reason `buffer` is too small for the result, then the buffer will contain garbage.

Comment: Try `perror(filename);` inside error block detected to have the C library hopefully help you.

Answer (score 2):

the array buffer's memory is only valid during your generateName function.
Even though you retain the pointer to the buffer using the filenam [sic] variable,
the pointer is no longer valid by the time you're back in the main function because the variable buffer is a local variable of the generateName function.

You should declare and allocate a character array as an static array instead
of just allocating a pointer, and pass that pointer as an argument into the generateName function, and write the generated filename there.

I hope this helps!

Comment: What about using malloc instead of `char buffer[80]`?

Comment: malloc would work just fine too.  Just remember to free the memory when you no longer need it!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two main points, and then are small errors.

This example compiles and runs on linux. It creates a new directory with a file "junk.txt" in a subfolder named from the date.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

void generateName(char* buffer);

int main(int args_c, char** args){
    char buffer[80];
    generateName(buffer);
    FILE * opening;

    mkdir(buffer, 0755);
    char out[89];
    sprintf(out, "%s/junk.txt", buffer);
    opening = fopen(out,"aw");
    if(opening == NULL){
        printf("couldn't write to file\n");
        printf("%s \n",out);
    }else{
        printf("writing to %s\n", out);
        fprintf(opening, "written in directory %s\n", buffer);
    }

}

void generateName(char* buffer){
    time_t current_time;
    struct tm *actual;
    time( &current_time );
    actual = localtime( &current_time );
    if (localtime== NULL ){ exit(-1);}
    strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer)*80,"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M", actual);
}
```

First, the generated filename was broken because you were declaring the array in the scope of `generateName` and once it goes out of scope it can be cleared or re-used. To solve this, I created buffer in main, and then passed that as an argument to `generateName`.

Second, this program uses `mkdir` to write in a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char *create_filename(const char      *prefix,
                      const struct tm *timestamp,
                      const char      *suffix)
{
    /* YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS is 15 characters. */
    const size_t  timestamp_len = 15;
    const size_t  prefix_len = (prefix) ? strlen(prefix) : 0;
    const size_t  suffix_len = (suffix) ? strlen(suffix) : 0;
    char         *buffer;
    size_t        len;

    /* Abort if no timestamp provided. */
    if (!timestamp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "create_filename(): No timestamp! (timestamp == NULL)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Allocate enough memory for prefix, timestamp, suffix,
       and the end-of-string nul byte, '\0'. */
    buffer = malloc(prefix_len + timestamp_len + suffix_len + 1);
    if (!buffer) {
         fprintf(stderr, "create_filename(): Out of memory.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Copy the prefix part, if any. */
    if (prefix_len > 0)
         memcpy(buffer, prefix, prefix_len);

    /* Copy the timestamp part. */
    len = strftime(buffer + prefix_len, timestamp_len + 1, "%Y%m%d-%H%M%s", timestamp);
    if (len < 1 || len > timestamp_len) {
         free(buffer);
         fprintf(stderr, "BUG in create_filename(): timestamp_len is too small for strftime() pattern.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Copy the suffix part, if any. */
    if (suffix_len > 0)
         memcpy(buffer + prefix_len + len, suffix, suffix_len);

    /* Add the terminating nul byte. */
    buffer[prefix_len + len + suffix_len] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}
```

Hopefully the comments are clear enough to follow along for new programmers.

Note that the expression `const size_t  prefix_len = (prefix) ? strlen(prefix) : 0;` uses a ternary operator, `(expression) ? (if-true) : (if-false)`. `strlen(NULL)` is not safe, and therefore we need to check that separately; `(prefix)` does that check. (It is equivalent to `(prefix != NULL)`, and can be read as *"if prefix is non-NULL"*.) Simply put, if `prefix` is NULL, it evaluates to zero, otherwise to the length of the string:

```
    size_t  prefix_len;
    if (prefix != NULL) {
        prefix_len = strlen(prefix);
    } else {
        prefix_len = 0;
    }
```

In your main function, you can use the `create_filename()` function thus:

```
int main(void)
{
    time_t     now;
    struct tm *nowtm;
    char      *path;

    now = time(NULL);
    nowtm = localtime(&now);
    path = create_filename(NULL, &nowtm, ".txt");

    printf("The path is '%s'.\n", path);

    free(path); path = NULL;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can use `path` as if it was a character array, after the `create_filename()` call (where it is assigned).  When you no longer need it, call `free(path)`. This is how simple dynamic memory management really is.

When the program exits (using either `return` from main function, or the `exit()` or `_Exit()` functions), the operating system will free all dynamically allocated memory automatically.  So, technically, there is no need to `free()` just before a `return` from main function, or before an `exit()`.  Still, for learning purposes, it is a good idea to get in a habit of tracking `free()`s.

Most common bugs are off-by-one, and use-after-free. In `create_filename()`, off-by-one errors are not possible, because the length of the prefix and suffix are calculated, and the length of the pattern generated by `strftime()` is explicitly checked.

To avoid use-after-free, I usually set the pointer to NULL explicitly after freeing it. (This is often called *"poisoning"* in programming: setting the value to a recognizable, usually invalid value, so that use-after-free is easier to detect.)  Many programmers do not bother, but they're just being silly. It's not like it slows down the program, or causes any harm; but it does make debugging easier. In this case, if you tried to use `path` after it is freed and set to NULL, your program should crash (due to Segment violation, NULL pointer dereference, or similar error; it depends on the operating system you use). In short, it just makes finding bugs much easier.

If you didn't set `path = NULL;` after the `free(path);`, and accidentally added a `printf("path is now '%s'\n", path);` after it, *it might work, or it might not*, depending on the system, the phase of the moon, and the mood of the nasal imps that may one day fly out of your nose due to Undefined Behaviour. (It's a joke: Undefined Behaviour is really undefined behaviour, and although anything could happen, it's not going to break your computer, or wreck your nose, we believe. It's just that it's really difficult to get the program to behave in a reliable manner if you have any Undefined Behaviour in it.  Accessing a freed pointer, or a NULL pointer, is Undefined Behaviour.)